# How to Prove the Intersection of two Sylow p-subgroups is non-trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

**I am working to prove that a group of order $p^2q^2$ is solvable, where $p\neq q$ are primes. Here is my solution so far.**

We can assume without loss of generality that $p>q.$ Consider the possibilities for $n_G(p^2).$ By Sylow's Theorem we have that $$n_G(p^2)\equiv 1\;\;\text{mod}\;\;p,\;\text{and}\;\;n_G(p^2)\;|\;q^2.$$
So $n_G(p^2)=1,q,$ or $q^2.$ If $n_G(p^2)=1$, then there is only one Sylow $p$-subgroup, and it is normal, call it $P.$ $P$ is a $p$-group, of order $p^2$, and so it is solvable. Also, $|G/P|=q^2$, which is a $q$-group, and so $G/P$ is solvable. So $G$ is solvable.

If $n_G(p^2)=q$, then since $n_G(p^2)\equiv 1$ mod $p$ we have that $p\;|\;q-1$. This is impossible, since $p>q.$

Now suppose that $n_G(p^2)=q^2.$ Let $P\neq Q$ be two Sylow $p$-subgroups, and let $R:=P\cap Q.$ By Lagrange's Theorem, the order of $R$ must divide $p^2q^2$. Since $P$ and $Q$ are both of order $p^2$, and they are not equal, this gives us that $|R|=1,q,pq,q^2,$ or $p$. Note that if $|R|=q,pq,$ or $q^2$, then $R$ has an element of order $q$. Thus, both $P$ and $Q$ have an element of order $q,$ which is impossible, since $q\nmid p^2=|P|=|Q|.$ So $|R|=1$ or $p.$

**How can I show that $|P\cap Q|$ must equal $p$?**

Since both $P$ and $Q$ have order $p^2$, there is an element of order $p$ in both $P$ and $Q$. Can I somehow show that there is only one element of order $p$ and then it will have to be in $P\cap Q$? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Yes, but we haven't covered that in this class, so I would like to avoid it. Also, am I wrong or is it Burnside?

Comment: Yes you are correct my mistake :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P,Q \in Syl_p(G)$ and $P \neq Q$. Assume that $|P \cap Q|=1$. Then $p^2 q^2 =|G| \gt |PQ|=\frac{|P| \cdot |Q|}{|P \cap Q|}=p^2 \cdot p^2$. It follows that $q \gt p$, a contradiction. Hence $|P \cap Q|=p$. (Of course $|P \cap Q| \lt |P|$, since $P$ and $Q$ are not equal).

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, if you deem my answer the right one please tick it at such.

Comment: I'm new to this site, it is done!

Comment: Thanks, yes this is the habit here so that everybody can see that the post has been answered. And... never stop asking good questions!

Comment: @NickyHekster A quick question sir, According to your argument I think you are using the second isomorphism theorem. How do you know that $Q$ is normal in $PQ$? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I am not using the second isomorphism theorem. The order of $PQ$ as a *set* is $\frac{|P||Q|}{|P \cap Q|}$. This is a standard property of subgroups, in this case $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: Rather than mentioning the order I should have said cardinality of $PQ$, since it is a set and not necessarily a subgroup.